# How to generate random numbers within a limit?

Tags: batch-file, random

I am creating a war game, and I need the player's health to be 200, 300, 400, or 500. How can i do this? So far I only can generate numbers from 1 to 500:

```
set /a rndnum=%random% %%500+1
```

and I don't want that. I want to be able to generate numbers 200, 300, 400, or 500 , but not 100.

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with your syntax, but I guess you want something like `rndnum=(%random% %%5+1)*100`,*ie* generate a random number between 1 and 5, then multiply by 100.

Comment: @High Performance Mark Is there any way to generate a number like 200, 300, 400, etc...?

Comment: My similar answer, below, crossed with @Compo

Comment: I want to generate numbers like 200, 300, 400, etc... but not 100. How can I do this?

Comment: I missed the not 100 bit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon your commented and different question, *to generate a random number of either `200`, `300`, `400` or `500`*, I would suggest this method:

```bat
@Set /A health=( ( %RANDOM% %% 4 ) + 2 ) * 100
```

It generates "( a number between `0` and `3` )", then "adds `2`, *to make that number between `2` and `5`*", then "multiplies either `2`, `3`, `4` or `5` by `100`, *to result in one of either `200`, `300`, `400` or `500`*.